# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a la información de un objeto en PHP?

Tags: php, openpay

Estoy integrando Openpay en un proyecto de tienda en línea, este tiene la opción de guardar las tarjetas pero veo al procesar el pago devuelve un objeto al cual no se como acceder a una parte del. Esta es una parte del objeto que devuelve, yo quiero acceder a [cacheList]:

```
object(OpenpayCustomer)#11 (10) {
  ["status":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["creation_date":protected]=>
  string(25) "2019-11-19T11:39:14-06:00"
  ["balance":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["clabe":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["derivedResources":protected]=>
  array(6) {
    ["charges"]=>
    object(OpenpayChargeList)#14 (7) {
      ["cacheList":"OpenpayApiDerivedResource":private]=>
      array(1) {
        ["trrvvvontamgl6tgqzkt"]=>
        object(OpenpayCharge)#19 (14) {
          ["authorization":protected]=>
          string(6) "801585"
```

Solo puede acceder hasta ["cargos"]. ¿Es posible acceder a esta información?

Comment: Al parecer trata de una clase y sus propiedades protected te impiden acceder a los datos por las mismas reglas de visibilidad. Revisa la clase y ve si tiene algún método que te retorne el valor que andas buscando.

Comment: Ok la voy a revisar, muchas gracias